# Locating elements through "begins with" method of CssSelector using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using selenium to locate and select a HTML element using `find_element_by_id`. I have had no issues with this until yesterday, when the web developers changed the ID of the element to a dynamically string.

Here is an example of what the ID looks like: `input_205`.

Before, I used `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_205"]').send_keys(viewId)` to locate the element and this worked perfectly, but now the number value in that string dynamically changes.

The only pattern I've identified is that it is a three digit number every time the page loads.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can set my xpath to some sort of "begins with" or "contains" so that I can still target the ID regardless of the three digit numbers after `input_`. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below XPath:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'input_')]
```

Comment: When I test that, terminal throws "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

This is what I have written: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, 'input_')]')`

Am I using this correctly?

Comment: @JessicaFeliciano , That's because of inconsistency quotes usage. try `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'input_')]")`

Comment: Update: I've modified my code like this - `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'input_')]")`

When I made this modification, I get the following error: "Message: element not visible"

Comment: You can refer this doc for waiting for visibility of element :http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html , on the very first example it is given that how to wait until an element is displayed. Also check if you are not in an iframe.

Comment: @dangi13 , FYI `ElementNotVisibleException` will not be raised in case element located inside iframe, but `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @Andersson I was able to get the CSS version of the xpath to work. Not sure why but it worked. The only other issue I'm having now is send_keys(). 

For some reason when I execute send_keys() method, I get this: "ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible."

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @JessicaFeliciano , as was already suggested, try to apply ExplicitWait as `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='input_']"))).send_keys("foo")`. If it's not working check if there is only one element matched by your selector: `print(len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='input_']")))`

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question that you *had no issues with this until yesterday* to locate the element through:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_205"]').send_keys(viewId)
```

That's because the desired element was having a static `id` assigned.

But now the element `id` is dynamic and getting assigned through some *JavaScript*/*AjaxCalls*. So to identify the element you have to construct a dynamic [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). But your code trials gives us the idea about the `id` attribute only. To construct a dymanic locator you can use multiple items from the below mentioned items:

- The `<tagName>` tag e.g. `<input>`
- The `class` attribute e.g. `class="input-full"`
- Partial `id` attribute e.g. `input_` from `id="input_205"`
- Angular attributes e.g. `ng-click="navigate('export',$event)"`

Most importantly, as the element is a dynamic element to invoke `send_keys()` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjuction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) method set as [element_to_be_clickable(locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable).

As an example, if the element is represented in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as follows:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
        <input id="input_205" class="input-full" type="text" ng-click="navigate('run',$event)">
</div>
```

Your effective locator will be:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input-full[id^='input_']"))).send_keys(viewId)
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input-full' and starts-with(@id, 'input_')]"))).send_keys(viewId)
  ```

**Note A** : Reference of the wildcards used with cssSelectors:

- **`^`** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*
- **`*`** : To indicate an attribute value *contains*
- **`$`** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with*

**Note B** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```